# Emacs ansi-term maximum buffer size?

Tags: emacs, ansi-term

I like running shell programs using Emacs `ansi-term` mode, but I wonder how to set the maximum buffer size in `ansi-term` mode so I won't lose command history even when there are lot of lines? (Google doesn't seem to give a obvious answer.)

Comment: Are you worried about the size of the scroll buffer or the command history?

Comment: @DrC Yes, I am running a program that generates a lot of output and the default buffer size would not fit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The variable term-buffer-maximum-size controls this value.  Setting it to 0 should buffer everything (haven't used it but that is what the doc says).  I'd be tempted to use a large value instead so a runaway program doesn't cause serious issues.  It defaults to 2048 lines.

```
(setq term-buffer-maximum-size 0)
```

in your term-mode-hook function should do it.